# How do you square a negative number in python

Tags: python, numbers, square

I do not know how to square a negative number in Python. I understand that you can do `x**2`, but if you use `-1**2` it comes out as -1, but -1 squared is 1.

Comment: What exactly are you typing?  I suspect an order of operations problem.

Comment: `i = -2`; `i*=i`; `i >> 4`

Comment: A browser search for "Python operator precedence" will solve this and related questions.

Comment: For example `2*5**2 = 50` not `100`. `-5**2 = 0-5**2=-(5**2)`

Answer (score 5):

Because of priority order.

```
print(-1 ** 2)
```

is the same as

```
print(-(1 ** 2))
```

If you want to square `-1` and not take the negative value of `1` squared, use parentheses :

```
print((-1) ** 2)
```

Or multiply it by itself :

```
print(-1 * -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this in the interpreter

```
>>> x = -5
>>> x**2
25
>>> -5**2
-25
```

In the first case, the -5 is getting squared.
In the second case, the 5 is getting squared and then negated

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I can get it to work as expected in Python, depending on how it's entered:

```
>>> -5 ** 2
-25
>>> (-5)**2
25
>>> pow(-5,2)
25
>>> import math
>>> math.pow(-5,2)
25.0
```

I think the reason why the first one doesn't work is because of how Python does the Order of Operations.

Answer (score 0):

You  need to use brackets around you negative number like this

```
print((-5)**2)
```

because of Order of Operations matter